# Get attribute of NSManagedObject parent class instead of an Entity

Tags: objective-c, core-data, attributes, entity, nsmanagedobject

I have a `Core Data model` with three entities and some of them have the same `attributes`. I should probably refine my model but I was wondering if there was a way to access the attribute of a `NSManagedObject` entity through the parent class.

Here is an example:
I have three `NSManagedObject` entities called "Object1", "Object2" and "Object3". All of them have an `attribute` called "attributeOfObject". I have an `if statement` where I check the class of my ManagedObject.

```
if ([self.managedObject isKindOfClass:[Object1 class]]) {

    // Here I would like to change the attribute of the Object1 NSManagedObject:
    [self.managedObject setAttributeOfObject:...];

if ([self.managedObject isKindOfClass:[Object2 class]]) {

    [self.managedObject setAttributeOfObject:...]; // for Object2

and so on...
```

However, it is not possible to go like this since a NSManagedObject class does not have this attribute. I would like to know if there is something possible like:

```
[self.managedObject.Entityname setAttributeOfObject...]
```

or something like this?

Answer (score 0):

With `NSManagedObject` and its subclasses you can always use key-value coding to access the entity's properties. If your attribute is called `attributeOfObject`, you could write

```
[self.managedObject setValue:someValue forKey:@"attributeOfObject"];
```

If you ever need to look up the attributes, you can ask the entity:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = [[self.managedObject entity] propertiesByName];
```